# Why is context needed here?

Tags: android

Im already read about context explanation and read context in others reference on google. but im need some practical explanation about context. 
this script

```
public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

what does those context do ? why should need context need as parameter. thanks

Comment: Who is the super class?

Comment: "why should need context need as parameter." - It needs access to your app's internal files.

Comment: why needed constructor with the parameter on context... what resource is needed on that script ?

Comment: Because `Context` is a God Object, you'll need it almost everywhere in Android.

Comment: sorry ur comment is very unspecific....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` needs a `Context` to create or open an existing database. It uses this [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)) to do so. But you could have see it yourself by opening the [source code of the class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java).

```
db = mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(mName, mEnableWriteAheadLogging ?
    Context.MODE_ENABLE_WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING : 0,
    mFactory, mErrorHandler);
```

`Context` is used almost everywhere in Android, mostly for accessing application resources, as well as performing various operations.

Comment: this link would be explanation in those answer : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Comment: I'm glad if it's clearer to you now. I just added a link to `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s source code as well. Cheers!